# Which is standard tag for hr

Tags: html, tags

I want to know Which is the standard tag type for horizontal rule `<hr>` or  `<hr/>` And another way, What is different between these two. It means some affects on not based on user browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5 they both are the same.

In HTML4.0 `<hr>` is used 
In XHTML1.0: `<hr />` is used.

This apply to all the elements that don't have closing tag (such as `br` or `input`)

Answer (score 1):

> `<hr>` is the correct HTML5 variant compared to `<hr />` (Which is valid
>   too). The latter is from XHTML. There's no opening and closing tag for
>   `hr`, you have to use only one. If you do like this `<hr><hr/>` the
>   browser will display two lines. `<hr/>` is actually an empty tag.
>   However, this one has a special meaning as it means to break up
>   sections of the code with a horizontal line.